# Pandas new column to find when cummulative sum reaches threshold

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a table in pandas that has IDs that repeat for each datetime. I have a row of the Cumulative Sum items, and I would like to create a new column that identifies when a certain threshold meets for each ID. I have an example in the image below. Here, I have the IDs, and I am looking for when the Cumulative Sum column reaches 6. Sometimes, the Cumulative Sum for an ID is 8, but that's the row where the minimum count of 6 was reached. Once the 6 was reached, I would like the next Cumulative Sum per ID, if there is one, to be false. For example, once 6 if reached, if the ID has another row with a Cumulative Sum of 11, I would like it to be False.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let us do

```
idx = df['cumsum value'].ge(6).groupby(df['incident number']).transform('idxmax')
df['new'] = df.index.eq(idx)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the following: 
idx = data['Cummulative Sum'].ge(6).groupby(data['Incident Number']).transform('idxmax')
data['new'] = data.index.eq(idx)

and received this error: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'eq'